# SSRS Layered Transparent Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, layered

I have 2 charts, one with a transparent background, that I want to layer on top of each other. When I do it in design mode, it works fine, but when I run it in preview, the charts separate and stack. Any help would be much appreciated.

Design:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, charts won't render on top of one another. :( You'll have to think of some workaround - like combining your data into a single dataset and creating separate series or categories to show your different values. Maybe this will give you some ideas - http://sqljason.com/2012/03/overlapping-charts-in-ssrs-using-range.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to take them in a rectangle.

See you